# Server in C accepting UDP and TCP connections

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a problem. I've been developing a Server in C that can accept UDP and TCP clients connections. So i need to know when a connection is UDP and when its a TCP. 
I've already developed both cases separately, and they work ok.

I've been searching about how to do this, and everything points to the *select()* function, but i dont know how to use it for this matter.
Can anyone show me an example or something accepting udp and tcp connections... I'm really lost there.

Thank you very much...

Comment: You're more likely to get quality answers if edit your question to include your code

Comment: `select()` (or poll() or epoll()) is indeed what you need.  A couple of jumping off points: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select, http://www.codingtree.com/c/c-sockets-select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open each server-side socket.  BSD sockets require you to open TCP and UDP separately.  Each socket, as I assume you already know, has a file descriptor, which is a small integer.

Once you have that ready, create a variable of type `fdset`, which is a set of file descriptors.  The mini-API for the `fdset` type includes:

- `FD_ZERO(set)`, which clears the set.
- `FD_SET(socket,set)`, which adds the socket's descriptor to the set (turns the bit on the integer).
- `FD_CLR(socket,set)`, which removes the socket from the set.
- `FD_ISSET(socket,set)`, which returns non-zero if the socket is in the set.

So, what you'll do is:

- Create four `fdset` variables.  One to hold your full list of sockets, and three scratch spaces for testing reading, writing, and exceptions.  Clear them out with `FD_ZERO()`.
- With `FD_SET()`, add your sockets to the full list.
- In your server loop, use `FD_ISSET()` and `FD_SET()` to copy the list of sockets from the full list to the read list (and others, if you need them).
- Call `select()`.  It'll look something like `select(biggest_socket_fd, readSockets, writeSockets, exceptionSockets, timeout)`.  The call will turn off everything in the set that isn't ready.
- Loop through possible socket numbers, asking `FD_ISSET(i,readSockets)`.  Hopefully, you kept track of which socket is using what protocol and can route execution to either `accept()` or `recvfrom()`.

Note that, to avoid starvation, you want to make sure your inner loop keeps track of where it left off last.  If you have a thousand sockets and you do something like `for (i=0;i<1000;i++){}`, lower-number sockets are going to have an advantage in service.

Comment: Something I didn't understand is why FD_ISSET could match the socket. Turns out select() removes all fds from the set except for the one with activity.

Comment: @user1869558, that's a good point; I've added it (and your correction to the `FD_ISSET()` call to the answer, even though your edit wasn't quite usable.

Answer (score 0):

Use select() below is the output from man select

```
select() and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more
       of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file
       descriptor  is  considered  ready  if it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O operation (e.g.,
       read(2)) without blocking.
```